# Can't Access Property of Public Interface

Tags: c#, interface, properties

I've defined a simple interface:

```
public interface Categorizable {

    string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Elsewhere, I try to use it in a function:

```
public void Add(Categorizable item)
{
    string cat = item.Category;
}
```

However, Visual Studio tells me "Categorizable does not contain a definition for Category".
How do I fix this so that Category can be used as an accessible property?

Comment: That should work. In fact if I put those two bits of code in my IDE it compiles. So I suspect there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: right click the type name and goto definition to see if it refers the same type intended

Comment: Ah, found the problem.  The issue was that I was declaring a class implementing List-related interfaces which iterates through ICategorizable objects, and declared it as ListDictionary<ICategorizable> when I should have just declared it as ListDictionary.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

1. Interfaces should really have an `I` in front of them i. `ICategorizable`, its very common and a standard for C#.
2. Check you haven't declared a class with the same name.
3. Check you haven't declared your interface somewhere else.

   - If this is coming from a class library, check you are actually using the correct version, and its builds with your project.

Other than this, there isn't much else that can go wrong. This is how interfaces work (without deviation).